# What's the difference between стихи and стихотворение?

Tags: выбор-слова

It sounds like стихотворение has something to do with творческий, so I'd guess it's more like epic poetry, but I was taught поэм/поэзия is used for epic poems. Is стихи just short for стихотворение?

Comment: стихотворение is a SHORT poem. Long, epic poem is поэма.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Стихи* (in its main meaning) is a mass noun ("poetry"), *стихотворения* is a count noun ("poems").

Compare:

> Да, стихи… Ему — тридцать два года!  В самом деле, что же дальше? — И дальше он будет сочинять по нескольку стихотворений в год. — До старости? // *М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита*
>
> Yes, his poetry… He was thirty-two! And what were his prospects?
> To go on writing a few poems every year. How long — until he was an old man? // *Mikhail Bulgakov, The Master and Margarita*

Note that *стихотворения* can be used to translate "poetry" as well, just like English "poems" can mean "poetry".

The word *стих* also has several secondary meanings, most of them corresponding to English "verse" (as in the Bible, or a part of a poem). In those meanings, *стихи* simply mean "verses". *Стих* can also mean "mood", like in *на него нашёл грустный стих* "he's feeling blue". *Стихотворения* can be used in neither of those meanings.

Finally, *стих* is a colloquial synonym for *стихотворение*:

> Прочли ему за услуги два или три стиха. // *Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)*

, but it's not recommended to use it as a countable noun except in colloquial speech.

Answer (score 2):

Стих = stanza

Стихи = verse

Стихотворение = short poem

Поэма = long poem

Yet the word "стих" can also be used as shortened form of "стихотворение" i.e. short poem. However it's a bad habit to mention plural "стихи" when you mean just a single poem (alas, it's a common mistake as almost every poem consists of several stanzas).

Comment: No, стих is not a stanza, it is a line in a poem, stanza is строфа, строфа состоит из стихов. Стих – строка стихотворного текста, организованная по определённому ритмическому образцу («Мой дядя самых честных правил»).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, **стихи** is just short **стихотворения** (about 4 strings).

Comment: It's a synonym (in some meanings), but I don't think it's a short version

Comment: no, it's a short version

Comment: [Словарь русских синонимов](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/171809): **Стих - см. стихотворение**. По-моему, синонимы.

Comment: Синонимы, но «стихи» — так и так уменьшенная версия слова понятия «стихотворение».